# How to create case insensitive CsvSchema ising jackson?

Tags: java, csv, jackson, fasterxml

I have the following CSV file:

```
field_1,field_2
  123, ewfwe
 .....
```

Lets take a look at the following code:

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema()
            .withUseHeader(true)
            .withComments()
            .withColumnSeparator(',');
....
MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> iter = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class)
            .with(schema)
            .readValues(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, replacingDecoder))
...
List<String> requiredFieldsForAdd = Arrays.asList(
            "Field_1",
            "Field_2"
 );           
 CsvSchema schemaWithHeaders = ((CsvSchema) iter.getParserSchema()).withColumnSeparator(columnSeparator);
        for (String field : requiredFieldsForAdd) {
            if (Objects.isNull(schemaWithHeaders.column(field.toLowerCase()))) {
                log.warn("Missing required header for add {}", field);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

This code returns `false` (because of case difference in columns names), but I expect to see `true`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is `columns` in `columns.column(field.toLowerCase())` in your code above?
Or do you mean `schema` or `schemaWithHeaders` instead?

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch good catch. it is schemaWithHeaders

Comment: @gstackoverflow, could not reproduce it. Is it still reproducible? If it is, could you please provide the Jackson Maven dependency definitions that you are currently using?